# SQL query in Ruby not finding DateTime in where statement properly

Tags: sql, ruby, datetime

Appointments have two fields, an `at` (a datetime) and `minutes` (integer, length of appointment)

appointment_a: `at` = "2015-04-02 21:00:00", and `minutes` = 60, which already exists.

I'm trying to create appointment_b, where `at` = "2015-04-02 21:30:00", and `minutes` = 60.

This is a validation in the Appointment model:

```
def check_overlap
  from = appointment_a.at 
  to = appointment_a.minutes * 60 + appointment_a.at
    if Appointment.where('at >= ? AND at + minutes * 60 >= ?', from, to).emtpy? == false 
      errors.add(:at, (" field will cause overlap between existing appointments "))
    end
end
```

Why is this not adding `errors`?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to add a `Time` to an `Integer` you get an error:

```
Time can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Maybe if you change your `to` variable declaration to this:

```
to = appointment_a.at + appointment_a.minutes * 60
```

This way, you're adding an Integer to a `Time` type, so there should be no errors

Comment: that's already what I do in my system, I didn't know the order mattered.  Any other possible solution ?

Comment: I think you're trying to check for overlap in the wrong way, overlap happens when either of these two happen: there's another appointment that starts later but ends earlier or there's one that starts earlier and ends later.
The way you're checking it, the query is checking if there's an appointment that starts after appointment b, and there isn't since appointment a starts before b. You need to rewrite the query to match your needs.